# Using Different Language in Voice XML 2.0 Prompt

Tags: text-to-speech, speech, voicexml

There is classic tag  which used for TTS (Text To Speech) in VXML 2.0 [ **prompt** ]

```
 <prompt>
        Which do you like better, dogs or cats?
 </prompt>
```

My VXML Browser can also able to make TTS suppose for French like this

```
<prompt>
        Ce que vous aimez mieux, les chiens ou les chats?
 </prompt>
```

How can I set the TTS values in VXML so that XML Browser will use  different language for TTS such as French?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag `<prompt>` has language attribute xml:lang which can be used to specify language according to [VXML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/#dml4.1)

Your browser might not support it though. You should better provide more details on the VXML browser you are using.